# Automate MapInfo with C#

Tags: c#, mapinfo

Hi I'm developing an application that parsing data then after that I want to visualize some data on map using MapInfo, I made a MapInfo instance correctly but till now I do not know how to display data on the instance or how to use it also the instance I've created is not visible even after I make visible.

below is my code

```
namespace JA3_Trace_Viewer
{
public partial class JA3Main : Form
{
    public JA3Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void JA3Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MapInfo.MapInfoApplication mapinfoinstance = new MapInfo.MapInfoApplication();
        mapinfoinstance.Visible = true;
        DDockWindow winM = new DDockWindow();
        winM.Activate();            
    }
}
```

The data that I want to visualize on map is longitude and latitude and another columns lets call them data, so please if you help me.

Thanks in advance.

The new code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Sets the parent of a window.
    [DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndParent);

    //Sets window attributes
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    //Gets window attributes
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    //assorted constants needed
    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000; //child window
    public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
    public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
    public static int WS_CAPTION= WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar
    public static int WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x1000000;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new instance of MapInfo.
        MapInfoApplication mapinfo = new MapInfoApplication();

        // Get the handle to the whole MapInfo application.
        // 9 = SYS_INFO_MAPINFOWND.
        string handle = mapinfo.Eval("SystemInfo(9)");

        // Convert the handle to an IntPtr type.
        IntPtr oldhandle = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(handle));

        //Make mapinfo visible otherwise it won't show up in our control.
        mapinfo.Visible = true;

        //Set the parent of MapInfo to a picture box on the form.
        SetParent(oldhandle, this.pictureBox1.Handle);

        //Get current window style of MapInfo window
        int style = GetWindowLong(oldhandle, GWL_STYLE);

        //Take current window style and remove WS_CAPTION(title bar) from it
        SetWindowLong(oldhandle, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CAPTION));

        //Maximize MapInfo so that it fits into our control.
        mapinfo.Do("Set Window 1011 Max");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't open any MapInfo table (a `.TAB` file), so there is nothing to display.

Comment: Should I get the mapinfo window in my form first, actually I think the mapinfo window is not oped in my form.

Comment: No, you don't get a full embedded MapInfo, with menu bars etc. As long as you don't open any table you don't see anything.

Comment: Hi, I opened a new table and tell I get nothing appeared, below is my code, please have a look.

        mapinfo.Do(@"Open Table ""E:\test.TAB""");

Comment: Compare your code with sample code from `\Samples\DOTNET\IntegratedMapping\IntegratedMappingCS.sln` in your MapBasic folder. Based on that you should be able to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Class `MapInfoApplication` has a method called `Do()` and `Eval()`, there you can pass a command string, e.g. `mapinfoinstance.Do('Open Table foo_bar.TAB as foo')`

Have look at MapBasic samples in folder `Samples\DOTNET\...` in your MapBasic folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I added a new code in the main post that I used and it's still not solving the issue, could you please see it.